# RubyRep Setup Cause Error " Exception caught: Mysql::Error: query: not connected: SHOW TABLES"

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I've spent the entire day trying to get RubyRep going, and now I'm stuck on the error "**Exception caught: Mysql::Error: query: not connected: SHOW TABLES**" for which I couldn't find much insight into.  At this point I've resorted to first trying to get RubyRep going on two local databases (to eliminate potential permission issues) but still no luck.  My current RubyRep configuration is:

```
RR::Initializer::run do |config|
  config.left = {
    :adapter  => 'mysql',
    :database => 'main_logger',
    :username => 'root',
    :password => 'password',
    :host     => 'localhost'
  }

  config.right = {
    :adapter  => 'mysql',
    :database => 'test',
    :username => 'root',
    :password => 'password',
    :host     => 'localhost'
  }

  config.include_tables 'app_logs'
  # config.include_tables /^e/ # regexp matching all tables starting with e
  # config.include_tables /./ # regexp matching all tables in the database
end
```

With this configuration if I run `# rubyrep scan -c rubyrep.conf` I get:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: In the next release, this will return the same as connection_pool_list. (An array of pools, rather than a hash mapping specs to pools.). (called from connection_pools at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500)
DEPRECATION WARNING: In the next release, this will return the same as #connection_pool_list. (An array of pools, rather than a hash mapping specs to pools.). (called from connection_pools at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500)
Exception caught: Mysql::Error: query: not connected: SHOW TABLES
```

Any thoughts on this and suggestions are much appreciated.

Kate

Answer (score 1):

Kate.

I was faced with the same error messages, but for Postgres. Spend some time and found this pretty guide:
[RubyRep Installation by wildcardcorp](https://www.wildcardcorp.com/blog/plone-relstorage-postgresql-bucardo).

I found broken source link to "rubyforge" there, this is alternative source link: http://mirror.as24220.net/pub/rubygems/files/rubyrep/rubyrep-1.2.0.zip

Other things work fine for me. Hope it will help you.